# Java - Getting Output from the program ... Command line arguments?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am writing a Java program and would be calling this in a DOS batch script....(it is a Swing based GUI application) I wish to get output from the Java program  in the calling DOS script. I am planning to get this information out through the use of command line arguments - like

(in the DOS script)

java myProg var

if (%var% == "loggedin")
{

}

var is supposed to be populated with the output from myProg. The Java program myProg is supposed to set the value args[0] (in var) and I am assuming this will be remembered when control comes back to the DOS script. 
Is this possible?
If not how can I achieve my use-case? What options do I have?
How can I pass a flag (as "loggedin") from myProg to the calling DOS batch script?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: try to use dos command "pipe":

```
Command1 | Command2
```

the output (eg: System.out.println()) of Command1 will be the input argument of Command2
The Command1 is the command which run the java app
The Command2 is the batch file which process args as %1, %2

Comment: That is not an issue, in my java program and in the script I can have a sleep command that can wait till the value in var is populated (it value in var does get populate at all)

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments cannot be modified; they are literals.  The only thing you can do is have text output to stdout or stderr (as yelliver suggested), set an environment variable, write to a log file of some kind, or return an exit code.

Comment: ...an exit code..
This did the trick for me. Thank you.
All I wanted was to pass a flag (indicator) to the calling batch script, so this worked

Comment: I needed this flag to be communicated out (to the DOS script) while  the Java program was running and therefore instead of exit code, pipe | proved the appropriate choice for me.

I had a System.out.print("mystring")  statement in myProg

then

java myProg | find "mystring"

echo "errorlevel"

echo tells whether the string is found in the output or not.


Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The way to "populate var with the output from myProg" is this (in the DOS script):

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('java myProg') do set "var=%%a"
```

Note that the Java program must "output" the value you want to assign to var, that is, it must show that value in the screen (via Stdout).